# How to enable / disable network protocols from C# code in Windows

Tags: c#, windows, networking

I need to configure network adapters through c# without using external programs like nvspbind in windows. I tried looking into NetCfg and managed to get at least the names of some components, but I can't find anything in it, like the enabled protocols for a given adapter. The documentation is very sparse and difficult for someone who doesn't already know C++, all the forum posts are from 2009 which makes me think this isn't how it's supposed to be done. I saw somewhere that it's possible to do through the registry but someone else had said it wasn't a good idea. Finally the last solution I saw was to just use PowerShell in C#. What is the proper way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the NetCfgx.dll and here are the P/Invoke declarations I struggled to find for anyone else in the future.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace COMInterop {
    public class Ole32Methods {
        [DllImport("ole32.Dll")]
        static public extern int CoCreateInstance(ref Guid clsid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object inner, uint context, ref Guid uuid, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object rReturnedComObject);
        public static uint CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER = 1;
    }
}

namespace Interops {

    public abstract class INetCfgGuid {
        public static Guid CLSID_CNetCfg = new Guid("5B035261-40F9-11D1-AAEC-00805FC1270E");
        public static Guid IID_INetCfg = new Guid("C0E8AE93-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E");
        public static Guid IID_INetCfgLock = new Guid("C0E8AE9F-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E");
        public static Guid IID_INetCfgClass = new Guid("C0E8AE97-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E");
        public static Guid IID_INetCfgComponentBindings = new Guid("C0E8AE9E-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E");

        public static Guid IID_DevClassNet = new Guid(0x4d36e972, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18);  // Network adapters
        public static Guid IID_DevClassNetClient = new Guid(0x4d36e973, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18); // Deprecated
        public static Guid IID_DevClassNetService = new Guid(0x4d36e974, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18); // 
        public static Guid IID_DevClassNetTrans = new Guid(0x4d36e975, 0xe325, 0x11ce, 0xbf, 0xc1, 0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0xe1, 0x03, 0x18);   // Protocols
    }

    // ----  Enums ------ //
    enum COMPONENT_CHARACTERISTICS {
        NCF_VIRTUAL = 0x00000001,
        NCF_SOFTWARE_ENUMERATED = 0x00000002,
        NCF_PHYSICAL = 0x00000004,
        NCF_HIDDEN = 0x00000008,
        NCF_NO_SERVICE = 0x00000010,
        NCF_NOT_USER_REMOVABLE = 0x00000020,
        NCF_MULTIPORT_INSTANCED_ADAPTER = 0x00000040, // This adapter has separate instances for each port 
        NCF_HAS_UI = 0x00000080,
        NCF_SINGLE_INSTANCE = 0x00000100,
        // = 0x00000200, // filter device 
        NCF_FILTER = 0x00000400, // filter component 
        NCF_DONTEXPOSELOWER = 0x00001000,
        NCF_HIDE_BINDING = 0x00002000, // don't show in binding page 
        NCF_NDIS_PROTOCOL = 0x00004000, // Needs UNLOAD notifications 
        // = 0x00008000, 
        // = 0x00010000, // pnp notifications forced through service controller 
        NCF_FIXED_BINDING = 0x00020000 // UI ability to change binding is disabled 
    }

    enum NCRP_FLAGS {
        NCRP_QUERY_PROPERTY_UI = 0x00000001,
        NCRP_SHOW_PROPERTY_UI = 0x00000002
    }

    enum SUPPORTS_BINDING_INTERFACE_FLAGS {
        NCF_LOWER = 0x01,
        NCF_UPPER = 0x02
    };

    enum ENUM_BINDING_PATHS_FLAGS {
        EBP_ABOVE = 0x01,
        EBP_BELOW = 0x02,
    };

    enum OBO_TOKEN_TYPE {
        OBO_USER = 1,
        OBO_COMPONENT = 2,
        OBO_SOFTWARE = 3,
    };

    // ----- Structs -----//

    struct OBO_TOKEN {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        OBO_TOKEN_TYPE Type;

        // Type == OBO_COMPONENT 
        //
        INetCfgComponent pncc;

        // Type == OBO_SOFTWARE 
        // 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string pszwManufacturer;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string pszwProduct;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
        string pszwDisplayName;

        // The following fields must be initialized to zero 
        // by users of OBO_TOKEN. 
        // 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        bool fRegistered;
    };

    // --------- Enumerations ----------//
    [Guid("C0E8AE90-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IEnumNetCfgBindingInterface {
        int Next([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt, out INetCfgBindingInterface rgelt, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pceltFetched);

        int Skip([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt);
        int Reset();
        int Clone(out IEnumNetCfgBindingInterface ppenum);
    }

    [Guid("C0E8AE91-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface IEnumNetCfgBindingPath {
        int Next([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt, out INetCfgBindingPath rgelt, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pceltFetched);

        int Skip([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt);
        int Reset();
        int Clone(out IEnumNetCfgBindingPath ppenum);
    }

    [Guid("C0E8AE92-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface IEnumNetCfgComponent {
        int Next([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt, out INetCfgComponent rgelt, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pceltFetched);
        int Skip([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int celt);
        int Reset();
        int Clone(out IEnumNetCfgComponent ppenum);
    };

    // ------- Classes -------//

    [Guid("C0E8AE93-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfg {
        int Initialize(IntPtr pvReserved);
        int Uninitialize();
        int Apply();
        int Cancel();
        int EnumComponents(IntPtr pguidClass, out IEnumNetCfgComponent ppenumComponent);
        int FindComponent([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]  string pszwInfId, out INetCfgComponent pComponent);
        int QueryNetCfgClass([In]ref Guid pguidClass, ref Guid riid, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppvObject);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE9F-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    internal interface INetCfgLock {
        int AcquireWriteLock([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] uint cmsTimeout, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwClientDescription, [In, Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] ref string ppszwClientDescription);
        int ReleaseWriteLock();
        int IsWriteLocked([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwClientDescription);
    }

    [Guid("C0E8AE94-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface INetCfgBindingInterface {
        int GetName([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwInterfaceName);
        int GetUpperComponent(out INetCfgComponent ppnccItem);
        int GetLowerComponent(out INetCfgComponent ppnccItem);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE96-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfgBindingPath {
        int IsSamePathAs([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] /*INetCfgBindingPath*/ object pPath);
        int IsSubPathOf([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] /*INetCfgBindingPath*/ object pPath);
        int IsEnabled();
        int Enable([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool fEnable);
        int GetPathToken([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwPathToken);
        int GetOwner([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out INetCfgBindingPath ppComponent);
        int GetDepth([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pcInterfaces);
        int EnumBindingInterfaces(out IEnumNetCfgBindingInterface ppenumInterface);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE99-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    public interface INetCfgComponent {

        int GetDisplayName([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwDisplayName);
        int SetDisplayName([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwDisplayName);
        int GetHelpText([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pszwHelpText);
        int GetId([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]out string ppszwId);
        int GetCharacteristics([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pdwCharacteristics);
        int GetInstanceGuid([Out] Guid pGuid);
        int GetPnpDevNodeId([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwDevNodeId);
        int GetClassGuid([Out]  Guid pGuid);
        int GetBindName([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string ppszwBindName);
        int GetDeviceStatus([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pulStatus);
        int OpenParamKey([Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] IntPtr phkey);
        int RaisePropertyUi([In] IntPtr hwndParent, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags /* NCRP_FLAGS */, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object punkContext);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE97-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfgClass {
        int FindComponent([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwInfId, out INetCfgComponent ppnccItem);
        int EnumComponents(out IEnumNetCfgComponent ppenumComponent);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE9D-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfgClassSetup {
        int SelectAndInstall([In] IntPtr hwndParent, [In] /*OBO_TOKEN*/IntPtr pOboToken, out INetCfgComponent ppnccItem);

        int Install([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwInfId, [In] /*OBO_TOKEN*/IntPtr pOboToken, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwSetupFlags, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwUpgradeFromBuildNo,
            [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwAnswerFile, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwAnswerSections, out INetCfgComponent ppnccItem);

        int DeInstall(INetCfgComponent pComponent, [In] /*OBO_TOKEN*/IntPtr pOboToken, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pmszwRefs);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE9E-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfgComponentBindings {

        int BindTo(INetCfgComponent pnccItem);

        int UnbindFrom(INetCfgComponent pnccItem);

        int SupportsBindingInterface([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pszwInterfaceName);

        int IsBoundTo(INetCfgComponent pnccItem);

        int IsBindableTo(INetCfgComponent pnccItem);

        int EnumBindingPaths([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwFlags, out IEnumNetCfgBindingPath ppIEnum);

        int MoveBefore(INetCfgBindingPath pncbItemSrc, INetCfgBindingPath pncbItemDest);

        int MoveAfter(INetCfgBindingPath pncbItemSrc, INetCfgBindingPath pncbItemDest);
    };

    [Guid("C0E8AE98-306E-11D1-AACF-00805FC1270E"),InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), ComVisible(true)]
    interface INetCfgSysPrep {
        int HrSetupSetFirstDword([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszSection, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszKey, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int dwValue);

        int HrSetupSetFirstString([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszSection, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszKey, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszValue);

        int HrSetupSetFirstStringAsBool([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszSection, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszKey, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool fValue);

        int HrSetupSetFirstMultiSzField([In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszSection, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pwszKey, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string pmszValue);
    };
}
```